# How to use if or casewhen to find same items and then substract its value?

Tags: jasper-reports

Actually I have totally no idea how to do this...but is it possible to use `IF` or `CaseWhen` to substract a value if the item is the same in the table? For example

Let say I have Table A and B -- there is an item called Sugar in Table A and B but their quantity are different in both table for example

- Table A sugar = 10 and
- Table B sugar = 20

Since there is same item is both table A and B called sugar I need to subtract

Table A =10 minus Table B= 20

The result would be -10...

I don't know if this even the correct way to do it...kindly advise if there is a better way.

Comment: This depends on your requirement. How should the calculation work? Then it is possible to put the calculation into the SELECT (if your source is SQL) or into some calculation in the report. But, again, this depends in how your rule looks like.

Comment: With table you are referring to jr:table component?, where to you like to display the result?, what kind of datasource are you using?

Comment: What i am trying to do is a table where in one table Called Plan there is and item for example A and in Actual there is also A ....but the value of A in the Plan and Actual Tables are different but their name are the same...so when it is the same i want the plan A substract actual A otherwise if either one does not exist do nothing or null

Comment: My idea is simply to identify if there are item the same between two tables then substract...if not the same do nothing...what command should i use